# Paste Data or Alternatives to CMD V simulation

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I used to simulate CMD V event to paste data from my app to the active app. However, it seems like with the new sandboxing restrictions this isn't allowed anymore.

Does anybody know another way to invoke a paste ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using AppleScript:

```
set the clipboard to "MyString"
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
end tell
```

From a cocoa application, you can run scripts with `NSAppleScript`. Assuming you have a file called Script.txt in your apps Resources folder that looks like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
end tell
```

you can then use the following code:

```
- (void)pasteInActiveApp:(NSData *)data type:(NSString *)type
{
    NSPasteboardItem *item = [[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init];
    [item setData:data forType:type];

    NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pboard clearContents];
    [pboard writeObjects:@[item]];

    NSDictionary *errorDict = nil;
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[self pasteScript]];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
    // Handle result
}

- (NSString *)pasteScript
{
    static NSString *script;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSError *error;
        script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Script" withExtension:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        if (error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });

    return script;
}
```

Now, all you need to do is call the `pasteInActiveApp:type:` method with the data and pasteboard type you want to paste.

On a side note, I don't think it's a very good idea to paste stuff from an application that is running in the background into the app in the foreground. First off, you don't know what app your pasting it in and even if you do, you can never know where you are pasting it to. The user might have a browser with a form that has multiple input fields (or similar). Also, the user might not *want* you to do so.

Edit: Changed the code so the data is set in the Objective-C code instead of the apple script.